# Unity C# - Having problems comparing two variables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this may be a dumb question...
I have two variables and I am setting them to serial data that continuosly changes (from an arduino), just at different times. Then, I am comparing them with each other to see if an object (The IKTarget) should move forwards or backwards(in unity).

Below is my code:

```
void Start() {
   //Starting a new coroutine
   StartCoroutine(VariableSetter());
}

//Using that corouting
IEnumerator VariableSetter() {
    //Setting the first variable to the serialdata
    controllerfinger1_Angle = SerialDataDecoder.finger1_Angle;
    //Waiting 20ms
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.02f);
    //Setting the other variable to the serialdata
    newcontrollerfinger1_Angle = SerialDataDecoder.finger1_Angle;
}

void Update() {
    //Making the finger movement frame dependent
    amountToMove = speed * Time.deltaTime; */

    //If the finger angle is increasing
    if (newcontrollerfinger1_Angle > controllerfinger1_Angle)
    {
        //Move the IKTarget fowards (Closes the finger)
        IKTarget.Translate(Vector3.forward * amountToMove, Space.World);
    }
    //If the finger angle is decreasing
    if (newcontrollerfinger1_Angle < controllerfinger1_Angle)
    {
        //Move the IKTarget backwards (Opens up the finger)
        IKTarget.Translate(Vector3.back * amountToMove, Space.World);
    }
}
```

When I run this in unity, the IKTarget object doesnt seem to want to move.
I KNOW my SerialData is correct as I have checked.

If anybody could provide an answer for this issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Isaac.

Comment: What happens if `newcontrollerfinger1_Angle == controllerfinger1_Angle`?

Comment: Could you just print both `newcontrollerfinger1_Angle` and `controllerfinger1_Angle` in the `Update()` method to make sure there isn't some weird behaviour making them equal?

Comment: I need the coroutine to use the delay

Comment: @ikerbera Ill add that in and make it print a message if the values are the same... EDIT: They seem to be the same, even with the delay

Comment: Yours variables are set to the same value - `finger1_Angle`, isn.t it an issue?

Comment: @Ivvan - that value changes: it holds data coming from an arduino and that data is continuously changing

Comment: You are only calling `VariableSetter` once at start. Is that the expected behaviour you want? Or you want it to be executed continuously?

Comment: controllerfinger1_Angle = SerialDataDecoder.finger1_Angle


    get {  return this.value;}

set { If (value > this.value) IKTarget.Translate(Vector3.forward * amountToMove, Space.World);
If (value < this.value) IKTarget.Translate(Vector3.forward * -amountToMove, Space.World);

 )

Comment: @ming060 , I want it to execute continuously, ill try calling VariableSetter in the update function EDIT: When I do call variable setter, it continuously moves foward. I tried what joreldraw said and changed the amountToMove to a negative to make the IKTarget move backwards and that made the two variables set to the same value

Comment: I call VariableSetter in the update loop like this: VariableSetter(); I dont think it is continuously calling the function, how would I do that?

Comment: I have gotten it to work... instead of calling VariableSetter, I had to start it like this: StartCoroutine(VariableSetter()); , but in the update instead of start. I hope anybody having the same issue will be able to resolve, thanks to everyone who helped